Is there a more efficient way to update Prisma composite tables?
For context, my schema resembles something like this:
model Plant {
  id                Int                  @id @default(autoincrement())
  // Omitted data here...
  climateRegions    PlantClimateRegion[]
  attractedWildlife PlantWildlife[]
}

model PlantClimateRegion {
  plant   Plant         @relation(fields: [plantId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  plantId Int
  region  ClimateRegion

  @@id(name: "plantClimateId", [plantId, region])
}

model PlantWildlife {
  plant    Plant             @relation(fields: [plantId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  plantId  Int
  wildlife AttractedWildlife

  @@id(name: "plantWildlifeId", [plantId, wildlife])
}


ClimateRegion and AttractedWildlife are string ENUMS.
my update function does as follows:
    await prisma.$transaction(async (tx) => {
      await tx.plantClimateRegion.deleteMany({
        where: {
          plantId: id,
        },
      });

      await tx.plantWildlife.deleteMany({
        where: {
          plantId: id,
        },
      });

      const climateRegionRecords = climateRegions.map(
        (region: ClimateRegion) => ({
          region,
        })
      );

      const wildlifeRecords = attractedWildlife.map(
        (wildlife: AttractedWildlife) => ({
          wildlife,
        })
      );

      updatedPlant = await tx.plant.update({
        where: {
          id,
        },
        data: {
          // Omitted data here...
          climateRegions: {
            createMany: { data: climateRegionRecords },
          },
          attractedWildlife: {
            createMany: { data: wildlifeRecords },
          },
        },
      });

I know that I could conditionally delete instead of deleting all, but I'm wondering if Prisma offers some sort of onUpdate referential action or other options that would prevent from explicitly deleting and adding?
// Workaround solution
I've tried the upsert action but unsure if it's possible in my use case, or how to use it properly.
As a temporary solution, I chose to manually delete all rows in the composite tables by Id, and re-add them. This works but this solution will likely cause performance issues as things scale due to inefficiency.

What are you trying to do? What is the problem exactly? Why are you deleting records? What exactly are you trying to update? Can you describe what the goal of your code is? Please [edit] your post to include more information.
